# CSS - Issue with link padding inside container

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have some `buttons` inside a `container`. These buttons have a `padding` as you can see on the `image below`. I need the container doesn't ignore the padding.

I've tried `box-sizing` with no success.

Here you have the `HTML` code:

```
<br />
<div style="background-color:#0f0;">
    <a href="#" class="button">EDIT CART</a> ......
    <a href="#" class="button">UPDATE</a> ......
    <a href="#" class="button">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</a>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<div style="background-color:#0f0;width:200px;">
    <a href="#" class="button">EDIT CART</a> ......
    <a href="#" class="button">UPDATE</a> ......
    <a href="#" class="button">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</a>
</div>
```

Here you have the `CSS` code:

```
.button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0778bd;
    font-family: "Tahoma";
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
}
```

And here you have the `JSFiddle` link: https://jsfiddle.net/ox6yzpfa/

[image: CSS - Issue with link padding inside container]

Any idea on how to solve this? Please, if you get it working, give me back a `JSFiddle` link with the code fixed.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are trying to assign padding to an inline element that <a> is. Try to use display: inline-block

Comment: I gave you the answer first. This is totally unfair. Whatever. `:(`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` is an inline element, which does not have vertical layout or affect other elements in the DOM vertically. To give an `a` element vertical layout, so it can affect elements around it vertically, make the element `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` depending on your needs. Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/ox6yzpfa/1/

Comment: That's the same thing I gave. LoL.

Answer (score 2):

By default, anchor tags are `inline` elements and lack the box-model. You need to set the `display` to `inline-block`:

```
.button {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0778bd;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  display: inline-block;         /* Add this! */
}
```

[image: preview]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u37Ljn3g/**

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to assign padding to an inline element, try this:

```
.button {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0778bd;
    font-family: "Tahoma";
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px
}
```